# How to add git module in Android Stdio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

I already said Bye Bye to eclipse and configured Android Studio 2.1.1 in my machine and trying https://github.com/gorbin/ASNETutorial this social network integration project.

I have downloaded a file ANSE-master.jar from github and dont understand how to use it in my own project,that can have the ability to integrate with social sites.

Can anyone guide me how to use these .jar in my project.If it sounds stupid please let it go as i'm the beginner in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File>New>Import Module then look for the module source directory enter and you are done but don't forget `compile project(':Volley')` in build.gradle (module app) then sync the project.

**Update: This won't work**

First set your Project to Android in Project view window.It would look like this [image]

Then you need to open build.gradle file (Module app)

There you should add these lines in `dependencies`

```
  compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.3.1'
  compile 'com.github.asne:asne-linkedin:0.3.1'
  compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.3.1'
```

now click on sync now. wait for for some time gradle will build project for you. Once it done you will have all these sdk inside your project.
Hope this will help

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Tst'.
 Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.3.3] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@4ef34986.

Comment: How to add ASNE module that contains those files @Zeeshan Shabbir